# Facebook Web Query

Tags: facebook, web, grouping, subscribe

I'm a super newby to facebook so please excuse my ignorance. I want to set up a  web site for an upcoming high school reunion. I want to query facebook for a list of all the members subscribed to our group high page for which, I am the owner. Is there a way to externally query facebook without having to develop an application/ I was hoping I can do a RESTFUL query from an application running on my home computer. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What would you do after you query the people in the group or page? Is it a group or page?

Comment: I believe it's a group. I would use their information(email addresses) to send them emails directing them to my class reunion web site. I'm trying to prevent having to manually gather the list of group subscribers.

Comment: You can't get their email addresses through the API.